# vim unmap everything (completely stripped down vim)

Tags: vim, editor, janus

Love vim. Tried Janus. Like the idea, but it's too slow, 100 plugins competing for keybindings. I want to actually understand what every vim configuration I make does.

Is there a way to "unmap" all vim keys or as much as possible. Remove most commands, etc. The point of this is an exercise for myself. I want a super small subset of maps, settings, bindings, so I can add things one by one as I need them.

Have you seen efforts like this?

Comment: You could try the original vi which has a much more strict/limited set of commands. I believe it's called "nvi" now (New VI)

Answer (score 6):

Try to run vim with the following command :

"vim -u NONE"

from man vim

```
   -u {vimrc}  Use the commands in the file {vimrc}  for  initializations.
               All  the  other  initializations  are skipped.  Use this to
               edit a special kind of files.  It can also be used to  skip
               all  initializations by giving the name "NONE".  See ":help
               initialization" within vim for more details.
```

It should start vim without any plugin or customisation.

Comment: +1, learning Vim with a ton of plugins is the wrong way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from

```
:mapclear
:nmapclear
:vmapclear
:xmapclear
:smapclear
:omapclear
:mapclear
:imapclear
:lmapclear
:cmapclear
```

starting it like

```
vim -U NONE -C -Z
```

will start

- -U without startupfile
- -C in compatible mode
- -Z in restricted mode

Comment: What for do you need compatible mode here? I never saw it actually being used.

Comment: @ZyX: The OP asked for `completely stripped down vim`; I'm not saying anyone needs that. I'm just pointing at things he could use

Comment: This is an awesome answer, because `mapclear` is quite useful when one wants to, for example, get rid of all the annoying mappings added by default on Windows, or to ensure that reloading one's `.vimrc` causes a "fresh start" (i.e. that removing a mapping and reloading the `.vimrc` will cause it to be removed from the current session).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do something similar and posted that on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/h5uk6/reducing_vim_startup_time_by_loading_only_some/) post.

I try to restrict the mappings I define in my vimrc and load only some 
plugins that I find essential.